# TDAmerica trading platform won't install after updates to Oracle 8.

Tags: java

I support my father who is 900 miles away. Since it became unrealistic to clean his windows machine of numerous spyware and sales toolbars, I gave him 14.04 LTS.

All has been wonderful. Calls are now limited to "How do I print this damn thing again?" That being said, now his trading platform will not run. Tech support have not helped.

Before they offered the Linux version on their site, I was able successfully to get it running under wine. We eventually changed over to their Linux file and all was good.

Recently they updated their platform since Oracle 7 is no longer being supported and you have to move to Oracle 8.

Problem: Thinkorswim will no longer run. Initially it cannot connect to its server to update its version. So far I have:

- Installed Oracle 8 (32 bit then 64 bit) manually, and through the gui
- Uninstalled and reinstalled the Thinkorswim package (manually and through the gui)
- Unistalled Thinkorswim and installed the Windows version under wine.

Now the Thinkorswim platform updates, but it will not launch. I get the following:

```
No JVM could be found on your system. Please define EXEJ-JAVA-HoME to point the the installed 32 bit JDK or JRE.
```

I tried installing java manually using the windows version through wine (as per a suggestion on Ubuntu Forums) and that won't launch either.

Can you guys give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

To get thinkorswim to work on ubuntu 16.04 [and other versions] you need a java version of oracle java 8. In java version "1.8.0_91" [java 8 update 91] the security settings will not allow thinkorswim to run so you need an earlier version [pre-java8 update 20].

I used java 8 update 11. Set the security setting to medium. Has to be the oracle version of java. Here's a link to old java versions:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html#jre-8u11-oth-JPR

You have to install "for this user only." Follow thinkorswim instructions such as do not run after installation completes. First uncheck the run when finished box, then change the permisssions on the desktop icon.

Ubuntu Linux Instructions
  |  Install (1 KB)

1. This installation requires Ubuntu Linux version 10.4 or later.
   Click "Download thinkorswim" to start the installation.
2. Once the download is complete, navigate to where you saved the
   file, right click the icon and select "Properties."
3. Once in Properties, click the "Permissions" tab, set "Access to
   read and write," check the box to "Allow executing file as program"
   and then, click "Close."
4. Now double-click the thinkorswim_other_installer.sh file and chose
   "Run" when prompted.
5. Follow the steps until you reach a checkbox asking if you wish to
   run the application. Uncheck the box and click "Finish."
6. After choosing "Finish," close all open windows and locate the
   thinkorswim file on your desktop. Right click it and select
   "Properties."
7. Now, like before, select the "Permissions" tab, set "Access to read
   and write," check the box to "Allow executing file as program" and
   then, click "Close."
8. You will now have a thinkorswim icon on your desktop. If you see
   this icon, you have successfully completed the installation process.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  It used to run fine under java 7 using the instructions here:
http://www.strategic-options.com/insight/thinkorswim-on-ubuntu-14-04/

But now you want to update your linux to oracle java 8 .  Seems to work now running it using sudo.