# Problem with installing thinkorswim

Tags: software-installation, permissions

I have Ubuntu on three computers, one 16.04 (this laptop) and two with 18.04. the same thing happens on all of them.

I download the `thinkorswim` installer file into `Downloads`, check the 'executable file' box in permissions, then, after `cd Downloads` and `ls`, I run "sh thinkorswim_installer.sh" as instructed in all the references I can find. In all cases the following messages come up:

> gzip: sfx_archive.tar.gz: not in gzip format.
>   I am sorry, but the installer file seems to be corrupted. If you downloaded that file, please try again. If you transfer that file with ftp, please make sure you are using binary mode.

Noone else seems to have this problem.
Can someone help with this?
Also, I have downloaded Google Chrome and it won't install.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TDAmerica trading platform won't install after updates to Oracle 8.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738103/tdamerica-trading-platform-wont-install-after-updates-to-oracle-8)

Comment: Not sure about thinkorswim, but there are two ways to install Chrome. Download [the 64-bit `.deb` file from the Chrome website](https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb) and run `sudo apt install ~/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` in a terminal. If that doesn't work, run the following in a terminal: `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'` **then run** `sudo apt update` **then run** `sudo apt install -y google-chrome-stable`

Comment: Please, also, limit a post to one question; Chrome install fail is one question, and thinkorswim install fail is another. Please create a new post to discuss just the thinkorswim issue, and click on https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/866263 so you can remove the thinkorswim issue for reposing separately.

Comment: What happens when you install the `chromium-browser` package with `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser` ?